# Spring Integration DSL message driven jms listener uses poller instead

Tags: scala, spring-integration

I use the following code to create a int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter, however, seems it is based on polling, as it return the data in 1 second intervals rather than responding to ticks.

The flow I defined as follows:

```
jms.listen(requestDestinationName = "myTopic", connectionFactory = connectionFactory).additionalAttributes(requestPubSubDomain = true) --> ...
```

The question is, how to make it message-driven?

Answer (score 1):

I checked the underlying implementation in scala dsl and found that it defaults to creating a `jms:inbound-gateway`(not a message-driven-channel-adapter), which internally uses a DefaultMessageListenerContainer. So yes, it is a message driven container internally but because it seems to be using a gateway component, it has a request/reply type of flow, this could be what you are seeing as a 1 second delay, instead of the polling.

Comment: Yes, I found that too. Is there a way to make it pub-sub?

Comment: I falling back to using MessageListener and need to convert JMS TextMessage to Spring Integration Message. Is there any simple way to do that?

Comment: You really don't have to do anything to do that conversion - Spring Integration automatically maps the messages from JMS to the internal Spring Integration message structure.

Comment: I see that it uses DefaultMessageListenerContainer. I have two options - either enable pub-sub semantics using inbound-gateway or write my own MessageListener, read JMS TextMessage and send it to further Spring Integraion flow (filters, transforms etc). To do that I need to convert the TextMessage I got from MessageListener to Spring Integraion Message. If do simply 
    def onMessage(msg: javax.jms.Message) = transform { m: Message[String] => handleMessage(m); m }.send(msg)
it throws Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsTextMessage cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Answer (score 1):

OK, as a workaround I manually create SubscribableJmsChannel:

```
lazy val subscribeChannel = {
  val c = new SubscribableJmsChannel(jmsContainer, jmsTemplate)
  c.afterPropertiesSet()
  c.subscribe(new MessageHandler {
    def handleMessage(message: Message[_]) {processMessage(message)}
  })
  c
}

subscribeChannel.start()
```

where processMessage(message) is my processing function, and

```
lazy val jmsContainer= {
    val c = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer
    c.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory)
    c.setDestination(dest)
    c.setPubSubDomain(true)
    c.afterPropertiesSet()
    c
 }
```

Please, be aware that SubscribableJmsChannel doesn't map JMS properties to SI Message headers! I had to fallback to using Spring Integration XML flow definitions.